# Common class for Linear, Conv1d, Conv2d,..., LSTM,

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

Is there any class that all `torch::nn::Linear, torch::nn::Conv1d, torch::nn::Conv2d, ... torch::nn::GRU, ....` all inherit from that? `torch::nn::Module` seems be a good option, though there is a middle class, called `torch::nn::Cloneable`, so that `torch::nn::Module` does not work. Also, `torch::nn::Cloneable` itself is a template so that needs type in the declaration.
I want to create a general `class model`, which has `std::vector<the common class> layers`, so that later I can fill `layers` with any type of layer that I want, e.g., `Linear, LSTM,` etc. Is there such a capability in the current API? This can be done easily in python, though here we need declaration and this hinders the python's easiness.

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `nn::sequential` can be used for a this purpose, and it does not need a forward implementation, which can be a positive point and at a same time a negative point. `nn::sequential` already requires each module to have a forward implementation, and calls the forward functions in a sequence that they have added in. So, one cannot create an ad-hock non-usual forward pass like Dense-Net with that, though it is good enough for general usages.

In addition, it seems that `nn::sequential` just uses a `std::vector<nn::AnyModule>` as its underlying module list. So, `std::vector<nn::AnyModule>` also might be used.